# Javascript only loading on hard refresh or inspect element with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, virtual

As title - not sure why this is happening, but everytime the page is loaded, it's complete - but it doesn't display.. until either:

1. Rotate screen (on mobile)
2. Inspect element (on desktop)
3. Ctl + F5 (on desktop)
4. Also works, when the WP-Admin bar is there (logged in vs incognito)

I don't see any other "network errors" but in console - see 2 "warnings" - photosphereviewer "navbar" deprecated - and devTools failed to load source map - /wp-content/plugins/360-viewer/data/assets/css/style.css.map

Here's the link: https://virtual-360.co/ctc/324060x/

It was working fine of coures up until it's due to be presented.. Need help please!

Thanks,

Comment: Open a new tab. Open dev tools for that new tab _first_, with the "network" tab preselected. Then put your page URL in the url bar and navigate to it. Look at dev tools: any network errors? Go to the console tab: any console errors?

Comment: I actually did that and "disable" cache and it appears to fix the issue on normal refresh. Other than that, I don't see any other "network errors" but in console - see 2 "warnings" - photosphereviewer "navbar" deprecated - and devTools failed to load source map -  /wp-content/plugins/360-viewer/data/assets/css/style.css.map..

Comment: missing source maps warnings are just that, they're not errors and don't stop anything from working. However: please put those details in your post, so that everyone can see what you already tried.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Re: try Mike's comment. I see a 404 for /wp-content/plugins/360-viewer/data/assets/css/style.css.map  That may stop the site from rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but if I give it a hard refresh - everything works fine. If I am logged in with the WP-admin bar displaying - everything loads first time, everytime.. Only when no user logged in, it remains blank - until the above events

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer. Source maps are never required to make things work, all they do is let you look at the pretty unminified version of CSS (or JS) in the debugger.